# import date.proto in other proto file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am new to protocol buffer. I have some java pojo class which has a field of type Date including year, month and day only.

For timestamps type, we can `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";`.

But for Date type, we cant do the same since date.proto is in `https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/date.proto`.

So how can I import this `date.proto`?

Comment: Is `Date` the one from `java.util` package or is it also a POJO type that you created?

Answer (score 3):

> For timestamps type, we can import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";.

Because `timestamp.proto` is some kinds of built-in message type included in Protobuf.

> But for Date type, we cant do the same since date.proto is in https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/date.proto.

1. Firstly, you should clone the whole project or simply download whatever `proto` file you need (in this example, the `date.proto` file).
2. Secondly, put `date.proto` into your project, you can create a directory for imports, for example: `google/type/date.proto`
3. Finally, generating code with `protoc`; You have to use the `--proto_path` command-line flag (aka `-I`) to tell `protoc` where to look for `.proto` files. If you don't provide a path, by default it will only search the current directory:

```sh
protoc -I.  --cpp_out=. usersvr.proto
```

This is the structure of my demo project:

```sh
╰─$ tree                                                                                
.
├── google
│   └── type
│       └── date.proto
├── usersvr.pb.cc
├── usersvr.pb.h
└── usersvr.proto
```

usersvr.proto:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package srv.user;
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/type/date.proto";

option cc_generic_services = true;
message BatchGetUserInfosRequest {
  uint64 my_uid = 1;
  repeated uint64 peer_uids = 2;
  map<string, string> infos = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 4;
  google.type.Date date = 5;
}
```

`date.proto` is downloaded from https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/date.proto

Comment: Even though this is working perfectly for a C++ project, I think the question was related to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Some Google time/date protos are in separate library (different from google/protobuf) so you need to add a new dependency. If you are using Maven, the dependency is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>proto-google-common-protos</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you add the dependency, you do not have to copy-paste proto files into your project (as it was suggested in other comments).

All you need to do then is to add import to your proto file (proto file name prefixed with its folder path).
For example: if you want to use timeOfDay.proto file, you need to add following import:

```
import "google/type/timeofday.proto";
```

This library contains following proto files:

[image]

Comment: Although this would be the best solution, it does not work.

Comment: @Tiberiu, I have updated the answer.. I have added explanation how to import proto file from external library. 
Did you added import into your proto file?

Comment: Yes, I added the import. [import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";] is seen but [import "google/type/date.proto";] is not. Not sure what is the difference since both dependencies are added to the pom file.

Comment: timestamp.proto and date.proto are not in the same library.
date.proto is in proto-google-common-protos library.
Try to find downloaded common-protos JAR and verify date.proto is inside. (Maybe date.proto is moved elsewhere in some version of lib)... And make sure you wrote import (in proto file) in correct case

Comment: Yes jar and date.proto is there. I added them in pom using:
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>proto-google-common-protos</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
        </dependency>
And in proto file with:
 import "google/type/date.proto";
 import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
With error "google/type/date.proto: File not found."

Comment: pom dependencies and imports in proto files look OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255892/discussion-between-tiberiu-and-smilos).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your Gradle (or Maven) setup working properly and generating code, you'll have to copy the .proto file into you protobuf source file (eg: `project/src/main/proto`). You only need to copy this (if you care only about using it with Java):

```
syntax = "proto3";

package google.type;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_outer_classname = "DateProto";
option java_package = "com.google.type";

message Date {
  int32 year = 1;
  int32 month = 2;
  int32 day = 3;
}
```

Then you'll generate the Java code with your Gradle task (or maven) and you will have access to `Date`, by importing like this:

```java
import com.google.type.Date;
```

After that, it's recommended to map properties of the `com.google.type.Date` to whatever type you are using as Date, it is better to not store the `com.google.type.Date` generated type directly. This will give you more control on your type whereas if you stored the generated one, you could not have the same amount of freedom as a Java object.

**note: if you are willing to work directly with `Timestamp`, there are ways to transform them to `Date`**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>proto-google-common-protos</artifactId>
        <version>2.32.0</version>
</dependency>

import "google/type/date.proto";
google.type.Date my_date = 1;
```